# What's the difference between 椅子 and 席?

Tags: word-choice

I'm sure 椅子 is more common but I can't find any information on the nuance of 席

Answer (score 6):

The difference here is very much like the difference between `chair` and `seat`/`seating` in English.

`椅子` quite literally means chair. See [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%A4%85%E5%AD%90) as well as [Google image search results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=784&ei=UOrwW4nrBIvEvQTalLPIAQ&q=%E6%A4%85%E5%AD%90&oq=%E6%A4%85%E5%AD%90).

`席` is a slightly more abstract term primarily used to mean "somewhere to sit", in the same way `seating` is used in English. `席` could be a chair, or a bench, or a cushion on the ground. Phrases such as:

> この席、空いていますか？ (Is this seat open?)
>
> 席が足りません。 (There isn't enough seating.)

Are fairly common, and while you might be understood even if you replaced `席` with `椅子`, it would sound very literal - you'll just be talking about chair(s).

Note that there is also a word `座席`, which is quite similar to `席` with minor differences as described [here](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/175476).

Comment: I'm not sure substituting 「椅子」 would make it sound at all unnatural, but it would make it clear that you're asking specifically about a chair (in the first) or talking about the number of chairs specifically (in the second).

Comment: Fair enough, it's a little ambiguous. 椅子 in the first one sounds unnecessarily specific to me, but I'll update the post - this may just be personal preference on my part.